# Asp.net FileUpload problem "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." ContentLength is always -2

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Hi all I have an update panel that works lovely in my test solution but when I put it into the main project it does not work correctly.
I've made it very simple, but still no joy, it consists of:

1. the file upload control
2. a link button

the link button has an onclick method that takes the file and creates a byte array. For some reason the contentLength is -2 every time. It does not matter what type of file I am using. Every time!
This is very frustrating considering it works fine in my test solution.

Is there anything I am missing or should be looking at?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

I am using VS2008

CODE:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />  
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" ValidationGroup="uploadform" CssClass="uploadbutton" OnClick="btnUpload_Click">Upload</asp:LinkButton>      
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var intDoccumentLength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    // will crash here as content length is -2 for some reason~???
    byte[] newDocument = new byte[intDoccumentLength];
}
```

Comment: Why not just save the uploaded file to disk?

Comment: Because thats not the specification

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel? You mentioned it in your question but I can't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: I am not, but other parts of the site implements update panels, I think in the master page. But I have removed the link from the master page and just included a plain old file upload control and link button nothing else,. not Javascript or anything and still does not work. Is there anything else that might be stopping it, maybe something in config or global?

Comment: Please post the code as part of your question instead of linking to it.

Comment: How big is the file in question?

Comment: @Lasse I would, but it looks a mess when I post the code as it gets filtered out

Comment: @Lasse it does not matter what size the file is, it's always -2 for some reason

Comment: @Funky, did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Mathieu, yes, get the same error :(

Comment: Could you please update your question with visual studio version, os version, etc

Comment: Have you tried to repair VS installation ?

Comment: @mathieu: I am using Vs2008, windows Xp, tried FFX and IE

Comment: @mathieu: I don't think VS needs repaired as this works fine in a blank test solution

Answer (score 1):

Your test code must be doing complete postback which is not the case for Updatepanel part as part of main project. With updatepanel, file may not have been uploaded at point of time when you are checking its contentlenght; this is not true for complete postback where file always gets uploaded first. In this case, it will always through you an error. This can only be done using an ActiveX control of some kind.

This article may give you nice hint and direction: [asp.net FileUpload event after choice is made and before submit for upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830899/asp-net-fileupload-event-after-choice-is-made-and-before-submit-for-upload)

Answer (score 1):

The file up loader is not working well in the update panel so if you are using the update panel then you have to use the triggers in the update panel and you have to give the name of the control or button on which you are clicking to upload the file

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FullViewMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test1" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="yaf" Namespace="YAF" Assembly="YAF" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="yc" Namespace="YAF.Controls" Assembly="YAF" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="FullViewContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">


   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload id="fileUpload" runat="server" ></asp:FileUpload>
<asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="Upload_Click"  Text="Upload The Image" /><br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<br />

<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" EventName="Upload_Click" />
</Triggers>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTime3" runat="server" /><br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

</asp:Content>
<code>
```

Answer (score 0):

As FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Length returns the same as FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength, did you check that your file size is lower than maxRequestLength (4MB by default) or specified in web.config :

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx

Comment: It's currently set to: 40960, I have just tried uploading a 4.71 KB sized jpg and still got same error