# Asp.net - Create a custom File Upload Control from scratch

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have tried using the FileUpload control in ASP.net and found some strange problems. 
I have decided to scrap this control and create a custom control. Is it possible to create a file upload control from scratch?

thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the default fileupload control?

Comment: It's possible, but quite a lot of work - what "strange problems" did you come across?

Comment: well, ith's not the fileupload control, its the solution I have to work wit, as it's a big pile of.....you know what! It's full of things wrong with it created by some idiot before me. I have got the upload control to work fine on a solution from scratch but in this solution it won't budge! see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502607/asp-net-fileupload-problem-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-conten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AsyncFileUpload is an ASP.NET AJAX
>   Control that allows you asynchronously
>   upload files to server. The file
>   uploading results can be checked both
>   in the server and client sides. You
>   can save the uploaded file by calling
>   the SaveAs() method in a handler for
>   the server UploadedComplete event.

Check out this:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: the async file upload control also does not work with this solution. Is there something that would block the file stream from coming through?

Comment: I know I'm WAY late to the game on this one, but potentially yes.  If there's a firewall on the network, it could in fact, interfere.  Some firewalls don't play nice with binary data being passed through web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Essentially your control will just have to render an `input` tag with a type of file, e.g.:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{       
   output.Write("<input type='file' />");   
}
```

However, this is a gross simplification of the problem...!

Comment: or I can just create it in the front end :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm not recommending this as a solution - just answering your question as asked :-)